# Doctrine2 & Symfony2 multiple count in one query

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I would like to make a request like this with symfony2 and doctrine :

```
SELECT 
(SELECT count(id) FROM table1) AS c1,
(SELECT count(id) FROM table2) AS c2,
(SELECT count(id) FROM table3) AS c3,
(SELECT count(id) FROM table4) AS c4
```

(note : this request is working in mysql)
However I don't know how to do it with doctrine,
I tried something like this :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$result = $em->createQuery('SELECT
    (SELECT count(id) FROM MyBundle:Table1) AS c1,
    (SELECT count(id) FROM MyBundle:Table2) AS c2,
    (SELECT count(id) FROM MyBundle:Table3) AS c3,
    (SELECT count(id) FROM MyBundle:Table4) AS c4'
)->getResult();
```

However it raises an exception :

```
("[Semantical Error] line 0, col 144 near ') AS c2,
': Error: ')' is already defined.") in
```

So is it possible to do what I want and if yes how ?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is beacuse with `$em->createQuery($dql)` you can only use [**DQL**](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) (Doctrine Query Language).

If you want to use **SQL** in a query, you have to do it with the [`Doctrine\Dbal\Connection`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.0/doctrine/dbal/connection.html), use `$em->getConnection()->fetchAssoc($sql)`.

Hope this help you.